# Accelerate vs Parallel Addition in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, simd

When benchmarking both of the vector and normal method there is difference in time.

Normal method

```
let arrayA: [Float] = [1,2,3]
let arrayB: [Float] = [10,20,30]

let arrayResult:[Float] = zip(arrayA,arrayB).map() {$0 + $1}

Time required: 0.0025310516357421875
```

with Accelerate

```
let p = double3(1, 2, 3)
let q = double3(10, 20, 30)

print(p + q)

Time required: 0.0009039640426635742
```

How it is working internally. It's become 2.79x faster in new method.

Answer (score 3):

SIMD stands for "Single instruction, multiple data". What that means is that certain instructions can operate on multiple sets of data simultaneously. Different types of hardware support different SIMD instructions. In your case, you were able to perform three floating point addition operations simultaneously.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD

Comment: Not 3 *instructions*, 3 *operations* simultaneously with 1 *instruction*.  That's the point of CPU short-vector SIMD: getting more work through the bottleneck of the CPU instruction pipeline.  It's also orthogonal to thread-level parallelism and instruction-level parallelism: you can have multiple cores each running 2 or more SIMD instructions per clock cycle.

Comment: And BTW, SIMD has power-of-2 element and vectors sizes, so it's actually (hopefully) doing either 2x `double` with SIMD + scalar cleanup of 1x `double`, or using one 32-byte vector with a "dummy" element of padding like you'd get with a `float3` 128-bit vector.

Comment: You are correct Peter. I meant 3 operations, not instructions. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, these are wildly different operations, so comparing them in a microbenchmark is not particularly informative. Your first example can add an arbitrary number of values, determined at runtime. The second example adds precisely 3 pairs. This means the first has to allocate memory for storage, which can be extremely expensive.

Also, make sure that you're profiling carefully, and with optimizations turned on. The first example is very subject to optimizations. The second isn't. Timing very small operations like this is extremely difficult. The act of measurement can skew your numbers a lot. (That said, I'm not particularly surprised by these numbers.)

But the correct thing to compare to would be this:

```
let p = (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
let q = (10.0, 20.0, 3.0)

let result = (p.0 + q.0, p.1 + q.1, p.2 + q.2)
```

That does the same thing as the `double3` code, and I would expect it to be roughly as fast. It might be a little faster or slower, but it should be close, since the optimizer will likely be able to convert it into something very similar to the `simd` code.

See Rob's answer for more what the SIMD code is really doing, but the key feature is that it is a hardware level feature that can apply the same operation to multiple values simultaneously. Not in the multi-threaded sense of concurrently, but literally at the same time by the hardware. But to use this feature, the input and output must be in very precise formats and layouts. (In fact, the `double3` you're using is actually converted to a `double4` internally, because the operations are done on 2 or 4 Doubles at a time; the last one is just ignored.)

Answer (score 1):

From Accelerate [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate):

> Accelerate provides high-performance, energy-efficient computation on the CPU by leveraging its vector-processing capability. The following Accelerate libraries abstract that capability so that code written for them executes appropriate instructions for the processor available at runtime.